# TypeScript, react-router and jsx: JSX element type 'Route' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jsx

Getting `JSX element type 'Route' does not have any construct or call signatures` while trying to follow this walkthrough [React Integrating Routing to Material UI’s Left Nav (or Other Components)](http://codetheory.in/react-integrating-routing-to-material-uis-left-nav-or-other-components/) using TypeScript.

My code:

```
const Routes = (
  <Route path="/" handler={Main}>
    <IndexRoute handler={ConnectionModule} />
  </Route>
);
```

causes the TypeScript compiler to complain on the Route and IndexRount imports with the above error message.

Here are my import statements (including to my own es modules). Note the imports from `react-router` toward the middle.

```
import { AppBar, Drawer, FontIcon, List, ListItem, MakeSelectable, TouchTapEvent } from 'material-ui';

import { deepOrange500 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import { getMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from 'material-ui/styles';

import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

import Router from 'react-router';
import { Route, IndexRoute, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router';


import MainState from './MainState';
import ConsoleModule from './ConsoleModule';

import ConnectionModule, { ConnectionModuleState } from './containers/ConnectionModule';
```

I'm using these versions of relavant npm packages (from package.json)

```
"material-ui": "^0.15.3",
"react": "^15.3.0",
"react-dom": "^15.3.0",
"react-router": "^2.6.1",
"react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"@types/material-ui": "^0.15.31",
"@types/node": "^6.0.32",
"@types/react": "^0.14.29",
"@types/react-dom": "^0.14.14",
"@types/react-router": "^2.0.30",
"typescript": "^2.1.0-dev.20160808",
```

Relevant links:

- [JSX in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3203)
- [Using react-router with typescript](http://www.mm1886.com/0510/using-react-router-with-typescript/)
- [react-tsx-starter/src/app/client.tsx](https://github.com/toddlucas/react-tsx-starter/blob/67fab175492e7596da0fb7a20157a6c39ccbe901/src/app/client.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in react-router definition file you need edit this: change the old global namespace called "_React" for the new namespace called "React".

this only happens using the npm types instalation.